# Hibernate get last update timestamp

Tags: hibernate, jpa

is there any way to get a timestamp of last update/save/delete of an entity (class/table)?

One solution that occured to me is setting some temporal property, but it requires change of DB schema and I dont really need the information when all entities were changed, I need only to know, that something has changed since my last lookup.

Other solution might be using hibernate events, but i think that its also an overkill...

So, is there any way to get this information from some hibernate class? Hibernate may have this info saved internally...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue using Hibernate interceptors. If you know about any better solution, please let me know.